# variable set to a empty string without assigement and want change value

Tags: javascript

I've created a calculator and I want the `operate()` function to be called once all values are not an empty string. For example `5 + 5` should call `operate()` as soon as the second number is entered.

Whats confusing me is the input field is displaying `5 + 5`  but when I `console.log` the `input.value` I get `5 +`   and `secondNumbers = ""`. I'm not sure why this is happening.

[image]

If you look in the console to the right of the image you see I get `4 +`  which is `console.log(inputdisplay.value)`

I'im not sure if this is Javascript being weird or if I've done something wrong.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const inputdisplay = document.querySelector('.input-display');

var firstNumbers;
var secondNumbers;
var operator;

buttons.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    firstNumbers = inputdisplay.value.split(" ")[0]
    operator = inputdisplay.value.split(" ")[1]
    secondNumbers = inputdisplay.value.split(" ")[2]

    console.log(inputdisplay.value)
    console.log(secondNumbers)

    if (typeof(secondNumbers) === "string" && secondNumbers !== "") {
      console.log("ran")
      inputdisplay.value = operate()
    } else if (button.classList.contains("AC")) {
      inputdisplay.value = ""
      return
    } else if (button.classList.contains("equals")) {
      inputdisplay.value = operate()
    } else if (button.classList.contains("operator")) {
      inputdisplay.value += ` ${button.innerText} `
    } else {
      inputdisplay.value += button.innerText
    }
  })
})

function operate() {
  intFirstNumbers = parseFloat(firstNumbers)
  intSecondNumbers = parseFloat(secondNumbers)
  try {
    switch (operator) {
      case "+":
        return intFirstNumbers + intSecondNumbers
      case "-":
        return intFirstNumbers - intSecondNumbers
      case "*":
        return intFirstNumbers * intSecondNumbers
      case "/":
        return intFirstNumbers / intSecondNumbers
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return "Error: " + e.message
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input readonly class="input-display" type="text">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="numberGrid">
      <div class="row-1">
        <button class=" button 1">1</button>
        <button class=" button 2">2</button>
        <button class=" button 3">3</button>
        <button class=" button 4">4</button>
      </div>
      <div class=" row-2">
        <button class=" button 5">5</button>
        <button class=" button 6">6</button>
        <button class=" button 7">7</button>
        <button class=" button 8">8</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row-3">
        <button class=" button 9">9</button>
        <button class=" button 0">0</button>
        <button class=" button decimal ">.</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="operatorGrid">
      <div class="row-4">
        <button class=" button sum operator"> + </button>
        <button class=" button subtract operator"> - </button>
        <button class=" button multiply operator"> * </button>
        <button class=" button divide operator"> / </button>
        <button class=" button backspace operator"> -></button>
        <button class=" button equals"> = </button>
        <button class=" button AC">AC</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your click handler modifies the textbox value after console.log when you press a digit. And its value gets used to parse the expression that will be evaluated for doing the math. Maybe you should first modify its value and then try to do the math or better factor things so that it's suitable to use the same logic for all the buttons. When I say "do the math" I mean setting the value of first and second number. Those are taken from inputdisplay but you should do it ***after*** setting its value with the corresponding digit pressed

Answer (score 0):

seems to me like you are just getting started, so i will not be going deep on best practices. and just help you get *this* code working. hopefully you understand what's happening a bit better afterwards ^.^

your click handler needs to be reworked

```js
   
if (button.classList.contains("AC")) {
  inputdisplay.value = ""
  return
   // return ~ rest of the function isn't executed
   // also it doesn't make sense as part of an if-else chain
} 

/***
// if you are operating when second number
// is input, this is useless. and would allow
// running `operate` on output
if (button.classList.contains("equals")) {
  inputdisplay.value = operate()

}
***/

// these are your main input "types" operator vs number
if (button.classList.contains("operator")) {
  inputdisplay.value += ` ${button.innerText} `
} else {
  inputdisplay.value += button.innerText
}

// evaluate **after** modifying `inputdisplay.value`
// note: you didn't use these values earlier anyway

firstNumbers = inputdisplay.value.split(" ")[0]
operator = inputdisplay.value.split(" ")[1]
secondNumbers = inputdisplay.value.split(" ")[2]

console.log(inputdisplay.value)
console.log(secondNumbers)

// checking if the input is "complete" and operating if it is
if (typeof(secondNumbers) === "string" && secondNumbers !== "") {
      console.log("ran")
      inputdisplay.value = operate()
}
```

because you had the check for "completeness" at the top of your handler, it would have worked on the *next* button click. any button.

so a user inputting  `5 > + > 5 > 7` would have *called* `operate` when they clicked 7. and then `inputdisplay` would have been

1. replaced with 10 by `operate`
2. the input of 7 is dangling/lost

---

now the serious stuff xD

1. if you have only *one* element of a certain function, use `id="input-display"` in HTML. and in JavaScript `querySelector('#input-display')` or `document.getElementById('input-display')`.

   - similarly for the AC button. `if (button.id === 'AC')`
2. that immediate calculation when "secondnumber" is input is most likely **not** what the user expects. also note that because of the way JavaScript event loop works the user will **never** see the second number being input. only the result of `operate` is seen after the second number is clicked

   - i recommend watching these talks when you're comfortable with JavaScript for better understanding of the loop

     - [What the heck is the event loop any way?](https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ)
     - and [In the loop](https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0) a more up-to-date talk on the event loop with its modern features